# Processing/loading huge gzip file into hive

Tags: python, bash, hive, large-data

I have a huge gzipped csv file (55GB compressed, 660GB expanded) that I am trying to to process and load into hive in a more useable format.

The file has 2.5B records of device events, with each row giving a device_id, event_id, timestamp, and event_name for identification and then about 160 more columns, only a few of which are non-null for a given event_name.

Ultimately, I'd like to format the data into the few identification columns and a JSON column that only stores the relevant fields for a given event_name and get this in a hive table partitioned by date, hour, and event_name (and partitions based on metadata like timezone, but hopefully that is a minor point) so we can query the data easily for further analysis. However, the sheer size of the file is giving me trouble.

I've tried several approaches, without much success:

1. Loading the file directly into hive and then doing 'INSERT OVERWRITE ... SELECT TRANSFORM(*) USING 'python transform.py' FROM ...' had obvious problems
2. I split the file into multiple gzip files of 2 million rows each with bash commands: gzip -cd file.csv.gz | split -l 2000000 -d -a 5 --filter='gzip > split/$FILE.gz' and just loading one of those into hive to do the transform, but I'm running into memory issues still, though we've tried to increase memory limits (I'd have to check to see what parameters we've changed).

   A. Tried a transform script that uses pandas (because it makes it easy to group by event_name and then remove unneeded columns per event name) and limited pandas to reading in 100k rows at a time, but still needed to limit hive selection to not have memory issues (1000 rows worked fine, 50k rows did not).

   B. I also tried making a secondary temp table (stored as ORC), with the same columns as in the csv file, but partitioned by event_name and then just selecting the 2 million rows into that temp table, but also had memory issues.

I've considered trying to start with splitting the data up by event_name. I can do this using awk, but I'm not sure that would be much better than just doing the 2 million row files.

I'm hoping somebody has some suggestions for how to handle the file. I'm open to pretty much any combination of bash, python/pandas, hadoop/hive (I can consider others as well) to get the job done, so long as it can be made mostly automatic (I'll have several other files like this to process too).

This is the hive transform query I'm using:

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
SET hive.exec.max.dynamic.partitions.pernode=10000;
SET mapreduce.map.memory.mb=8192;
SET mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=10240;

ADD FILE transform.py;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE final_table
PARTITION (date,hour,zone,archetype,event_name)
SELECT TRANSFORM (*)
USING "python transform.py"
AS device_id,timestamp,json_blob,date,hour,zone,archetype,event_name
FROM (
SELECT *
FROM event_file_table eft
JOIN meta_table m ON eft.device_id=m.device_id
WHERE m.name = "device"
) t
;
```

And this is the python transform script:

```py
import sys
import json
import pandas as pd

INSEP='\t'
HEADER=None

NULL='\\N'
OUTSEP='\t'

cols = [# 160+ columns here]
metaCols =['device_id','meta_blob','zone','archetype','name']

df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin, sep=INSEP, header=HEADER, 
                 names=cols+metaCols, na_values=NULL, chunksize=100000, 
                 parse_dates=['timestamp'])

for chunk in df:
    chunk = chunk.drop(['name','meta_blob'], axis=1)
    chunk['date'] = chunk['timestamp'].dt.date
    chunk['hour'] = chunk['timestamp'].dt.hour
    for name, grp in chunk.groupby('event_name'):
        grp = grp.dropna(axis=1, how='all') \
              .set_index(['device_id','timestamp','date','hour',
                          'zone','archetype','event_name']) \

        grp = pd.Series(grp.to_dict(orient='records'),grp.index) \
                .to_frame().reset_index() \
                .rename(columns={0:'json_blob'})
        grp = grp[['device_id',timestamp','blob',
                   'date','hour','zone','archetype','event_name']]

        grp.to_csv(sys.stdout, sep=OUTSEP, index=False, header=False)
```

Depending on the yarn configurations, and what hits the limits first, I've received error messages:

1. Error: Java heap space
2. GC overhead limit exceeded
3. over physical memory limit

---

Update, in case anybody has similar issues.
I did eventually manage to get this done. In our case, what seemed to work best was to use awk to split the file by date and hour. This allowed us to reduce memory overhead for partitions because we could load in a few hours at a time rather than potentially having hundreds of hourly partitions (multiplied by all the other partitions we wanted) to try to keep in memory and load at once. Running the file through awk took several hours, but could be done in parallel with loading another already split file into hive.

Here's the bash/awk I used for splitting the file:

```
gzip -cd file.csv.gz |
tail -n +2 |
awk -F, -v MINDATE="$MINDATE" -v MAXDATE="$MAXDATE" \
    '{
        if ( ($5>=MINDATE) && ($5<MAXDATE) ) {
            split($5, ts, "[: ]");
            print | "gzip > file_"ts[1]"_"ts[2]".csv.gz"
            }
    }'
```

where, obviously, the 5th column of the file was the timestamp, and MINDATE and MAXDATE were used to filter out dates we did not care about. This split the timestamp by spaces and colons so the first part of the timestamp was the date and the second the hour (third and fourth would be minutes and seconds) and used that to direct the line to the appropriate output file.

Once the the file was split by hour, I loaded the hours several at a time into a temporary hive table and proceeded with basically the same transform mentioned above.